# Date popup select wrap

Tags: datetime

I want to wrap date popup selects in `<div>` to customize drop-down button of the select. But I can't find where to wrap it. I don't want to use jquery for such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to override an existing theme function in order alter the HTML output for the date popups. You can override a theme function either from within your template.php file within your theme, or from within a custom module.

Whenever I need to identify the correct theme function to override in a hurry, I use a module called [Devel Themer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer). It allows you to click on any on page element, and provides you with a great break down of all the theme functions and variables associated with the element you're trying to override.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT: including theme function link**

The theme function you need to override is [theme_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_select/7)

Comment: I used it. It shows me nothing. Just standart theme tpl

Comment: do you see the checkbox in the bottom right hand corner of your browser with a checkbox allowing Theme Developer to be enabled? If you've enabled the module and still don't see it, there's a javascript error on your page which is not allowing devel themer to load

Comment: i see it and enabled it

Comment: updated my answer with the theme function you need to override